# How do I reverse engineer a PostgreSQL 9.6.6 database for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a database in PostgreSQL 9.6.6 already defined, how do I reverse engineer that into Ruby on Rails?

[Please don't flame me if this has already been asked, I couldn't find an answer when I searched.]

Thank you.

Comment: I think it'd be easier on you if you seed new database. Can you show schema for existing database?

Comment: The database has a rather large number of tables and relations in it. To code the database in rails would take days if not a couple of weeks, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody correct me if I'm wrong:

It would seem to me that since rails determines what columns are in a table by actually looking at the table definition in the database, that we (I) don't have to "reverse engineer" the database.

If rails is interrogating the database for the definitions, then the only thing we would have to do is define the relationships in the ORM classes and that we don't have to create migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Understood, i read your comment. But the thing is, Model with relations and attributes in rails provide by [Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html), in fact you cant export all stuff from random database.

You need to create migrations/models with [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and object attributes, and after that [Seed](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) new database.